# Apache airflow: install two instances in the same local machine

Tags: airflow

I have an Airflow instance in a local Ubuntu machine. This instance doesn't work very well, so I would like to install it again. The problem is that I can't delete the current instance, because it is used by other people, so I would like to create a new Airflow instance in the same machine to put various dags there.

How could I do it? I created a different virtual environment, but I don't know how to install a second airflow server in that environment, which works in parallel with the current airflow.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. use different port for webserver
2. use different AIRFLOW_HOME  variable
3. use different sql_alchemy_conn (to point to a different database)
4. copy the deployment you have to start/stop your airflow components.

Depending on your deployment you might somehew record process id of your running airflow (so called pid-files) or have some other way to determine which processes are running. But that is nothing airflow-specific, this is something that is specific for your deployment.